# Dynamically outputting checkboxes to aspx page in VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

I have 50 checkboxes that I need to write onto an aspx page. Each checkbox comes with 3 textboxes.

Example:

```
chkbox State   Name   donation  new donation
chkbox CA      Sam     10        15
chkbox AK      Sam     15        20
```

Now this shall go for all 50 states, depending on which states the person wishes to donate. In each state's row shall be a checkbox. So initially the page shall have value 0.00 in donation and new donation checkboxes, but all 50 states shall be visible. When the person puts a value of donation in certain state, that state shall get "checked" value and the donation, after submitting. On reloading, the value shall be populated automatically and checkbox checked automatically.

- How do I make these 50 checkboxes in VB.NET?
- Do I have to write the table in .aspx with 50 `<tr>` tags, and then have VB.NET code populate it?
- Can I otherwise dynamically write these checkboxes from VB.NET code?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need recursion for something like this. You need [looping](http://www.startvbdotnet.com/language/loops.aspx) constructs like `For` or `While`.

You can create an [array](http://www.startvbdotnet.com/language/arrays.aspx) of checkboxes with a size of 50:

```
Dim checkboxs(50) as Checkbox
```

Comment: but every checkbox shall have 3 textboxes on the same row. could you write a little more descriptive example please? or a link to read. Thank you for your help

Comment: I would recommend a UserControl like @hawbsl suggested. Here is some rough code of what @Oded was talking about Dim LotsOfCheckboxes(50) as Checkbox
For i as Integer = 0 to ListOfCheckBoxes.Count -1
LotsOfCheckBoxes.(i) = New Checkbox
LotsOfCheckBoxes.Checked = True  
Page.Controls.Add(ListOfCheckBoxes(i))
End For

Answer (score 1):

To handle the fact that each checkbox comes with three textboxes consider creating a UserControl.

There are lots of example tutorials out there. Here's [one](http://www.vbdotnetheaven.com/Uploadfile/mgold/AddRemoveUserControls04262005080452AM/AddRemoveUserControls.aspx).